# Origodb - Why "Do expensive preparation or validation in Command.Prepare() because it will not block readers"

Tags: transactions, origodb

Text taken from [here](http://dev.origodb.com/docs/transactions/).

Please explain what readers have to do with transactions.

**Inmutable + 1 updater + in-memory should make stuff so simple.**

I assumed that Origodb was built using inmutable datastructures, i.e. the readers would just continue to work using the data before the transaction. And, when the readers are finished, the readers reference to the database will be dropped, and the GC will clean away the old data.

I do not even understand why the Prepare part is critical for Origodb-transactions, since there is only one updater, so any exception during the Prepare or Execute will just abort the transaction, and Origodb continues to use the database before the failed transaction was started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OrigoDB supports immutable data structures and lock-free MVCC transactions but it is not the default. The default mode is shared mutable state using a global `ReaderWriterLockSlim` for synchronization. The `Prepare()` method is called when the lock is in the upgrade mode.